# emacs verilog-mode local variables not parsed

Tags: variables, emacs, verilog

I'm trying to set some Verilog-mode local variables in the SystemVerilog file itself such as:

```
// Local Variables:
// verilog-library-flags:("-y ../../../ip_lib/")
// verilog-typedef-regexp: ".*_t$"
// verilog-auto-reg-input-assigned-ignore-regexp: ".*")
// End:
```

And then I call emacs in command line to generate the code:

```
emacs --batch ./test.sv    -f verilog-batch-auto
```

But that tells me it cannot find module that is supposed to be in ../../../ip_lib/

But then if I use:

```
emacs -q   --eval='(progn (setq-default verilog-library-flags "-y ../../../ip_lib") (setq-default verilog-typedef-regexp ".*_t$"))' --batch ./test.sv    -f verilog-batch-auto
```

it works. What is the issue ?

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use verilog, but glancing at your examples I can see that

```
(setq-default verilog-library-flags "-y ../../../ip_lib")
```

and

```
// verilog-library-flags:("-y ../../../ip_lib/")
```

are setting different types.  The former is a string value, while the latter is a *list* value (containing a single item, being a string).

So that's presumably the issue.

Comment: I tried

    // verilog-library-flags:"-y ../../../ip_lib/"

but it didn't work either. Is it what you suggested ?

Comment: It looks like `verilog-library-flags` *is* supposed to be a list, so the non-list value seeming to work is curious, but I haven't dug into that.

Comment: What does `emacs --batch ./test.sv --eval "(message \"%S\" (list verilog-library-flags verilog-typedef-regexp verilog-auto-reg-input-assigned-ignore-regexp))"` output?

Comment: Congrats @phils - you've taken the top spot in Emacs.

Comment: Cheers, @TreyJackson.  It took me a couple of minutes to even figure out what that meant, but I see it now.  I didn't realise that was impending.  And it only took 12 years to catch up to you :)  I can recall that you were all over the Emacs questions when I started using the site, and your answers helped me learn and were inspiring, so thank you for the stellar community work.  Cheers to us both, I guess!